# Keep lan connection alive while going to sleep

Tags: windows-7, sleep, lan, thinkpad

Is it possible to keep lan connection alive when going to sleep? Although I would like a laptop independent(in general) answer, my laptop is Thinkpad T500 and the power manager shows in PCI options, the following three option regarding saving link state power: Off, moderate, maximum.
Also instant resume apparently does something different, so that isn't much help either.

I'm on Windows-7.

Here's why:

I'm a student, and currently I keep my laptop on almost all the time, but sometimes I sleep it and then I require to check something, so I turn it on. But then internet starts in at least a minute. So I avoid even putting it to sleep. 
I want that the internet connection should persist, so that I can put it to sleep to avoid power consumption.

Comment: Clarification required: What do wish to achieve by keeping LAN connection alive while your laptop is in Sleep? Want to know how this would be different from Wake-up-on-LAN. I expect your LAN port is not bridging or routing anything so when the laptop is aSleep what would your LAN port want to do?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the PC can continue Network activity while in sleep mode.  If the issue is the PC going to sleep while downloading/using the network why not just disable the sleep mode?  Maybe you already thought of that, but just checking ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you tell it to be [wakeable from lan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake_on_lan) then the network card stays on in a almost-asleep state listening for magic packets. I believe it requires a BIOS setting, google "wake on lan" with your computer model. Most of the results seem to be about the drivers (so update them), but also [this.](http://notebookblogonline.com/fixing-sleep-mode-problem-on-lenovo-thinkpad-t400-and-t500/)